# How to create live stream in C#?

Tags: c#, html, streaming, live, mpeg

I am searching for how to create mpeg stream in C# and forward it to HTML5. 
I am receiving (live) continous bitmaps from an IpCamera. I have to give these bitmaps as source to the mpeg stream creator and then forward to the HTML5 client (live display).

I could not found any stream creator for the live images. And how can I send stream to HTML5? do I need any server in between HTML5 and C#? 
PS: My client has already connected to C# with websockets.

Please give me some suggestions.
Thanks you.

Comment: You can imitate streaming with a response that has no Content-Length header and the `<video>` element. Streaming per se is not something that HTML5 supports at this time.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.My HTML5 is connecting to C# app using websockets. And both are communicating (continuously) using JSON data. That communication has nothing to do with presenting video (streaming). So how can I imitate streaming without any disturabnce to the other communication? please suggest me any related examples or tutorials.. thank you

Comment: I have suggested. Respond with no `Content-Length` header.